# Transactions in Cross-appserver calls

Tags: progress-4gl

Progress version 10c.

Suppose I have two different appservers, let's call one X and the other Y, each pointing at a different DB instance.

If I have a .p process running on X and using (locking) some records on X.db, and in the middle of it I invoke a process on appserver Y, in order to manipulate records on Y.db... do I get a correct "behaviour" in case of failures?

I.e.

- Y process fails, X process can detect it and rollback (on its own or by forcing it in the code itself.
- X process fails *after* having successfully invoked Y process, Y rollbacks any changes.
- X commits after Y has committed: both have updated their respective data and released all locks

Even if this work, are there any specific caveats I should be wary about? 
What about performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic linking of transaction states between the two processes.  An app server is just another session -- it is no different than another user.  The two sessions just happen to have a communication channel between them but there is no TRX state coordination.

In scenario 1 if the app server call fails it can return an error code.  The parent process can then decide what it wants to do via code.  But not all TRX failures will return to the caller (think "kill -9"...)  And application driven error logic can have bugs.

In scenario 2 Y will have committed independently of X.  No rollback will occur.

I don't see that scenario 3 is any different than scenario 2.  If one of these is an asynchronous call it still doesn't matter, the transactions are still distinct from one another.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything in the Progress stack that could provide this kind of service (excluding stuff built on top of Sonic, which is out of question for licensing reasons)?

Comment: Are you asking for transactions that span process boundaries?

Comment: The *DB* supports JTA Distributed Transactions.  But the 4GL has no specific support for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll investigate that part a bit more